# Каким лучшим способом откатиться до раннего комита

Tags: git, контроль-версий

Вот мои коммиты иду снизу. Сделал работу в master, сделал работу в branch 2. Слился.  Внезапно обнаружил (или захотел) что я хочу вернуться в branch 2, а ещё и вернутюся на первый коммит этой ветки и начать работу с ней. Как это лучше сделать? 
Переключится на ветку я умею. 
А как переключится на старый комит лучшим способом?

```
git checkout commit_hash ?
git checkout reset ---hard HEAD~1 ?
git checkout -b branch_3 ?
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит "лучшим способом"?

Comment: то и значит, чтобы руки не сломали в команде, чтобы мержить было просто и легко. чтобы не было проблем. вот это и значит лучший способ

Comment: я не очень понимаю саму возможность чекаутнуть коммит по-разному.

Comment: например написать reset --head это ведь тоже вернёт меня на прошлый комит...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git branch branchname <sha1-of-commit>
```

или

```
git branch branchname HEAD~2
```

или

```
git checkout -b branchname <commit>
```

Comment: хорошо, checkout. ладно. A reset тогда для чего?

Comment: @arg, http://stackoverflow.com/q/3639342/4827341